# Rails counter_cache update too slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3. I have the following:

```
# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country, :touch => true, :counter_cache => :total_shops
  ...
end

# shops_controller.rb
class ShopsController < ApplicationController  
  def create
    ...
    @shop.save
    @new_total_shops = @country.total_shops
  end
end
```

Let's say initial `@country.total_shops` is `2`, then when it's created, it should be incremented to `3`, but when I try `abort(@country.total_shops)` right after the line `@shop.save`, it still shows `2`. When I refresh the page, it shows `3`. I guess it just gets updated a bit slow.

How can I get the latest value quickly?

Thanks.

Comment: When the "create" methods is executed, is the page itself refreshed, and the wrong result is shown on the page which rails shows after executing "create" (so on "show"), or does this happen in a custom view?

Comment: The page is not refreshed on its own. I actually want to pass the `@new_total_shops` out to a javascript view for ajax update.

Comment: What happens if you move "@new_total_shops = @country.total_shops" before "@shop.save" ? You can always wrap both in transaction for consistency - ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do ... end

Comment: Tried both. Negative. Still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that since you've (I assume) already loaded the `Country` instance before you save the new shop, you're seeing the `total_shops` value as it was when the country was loaded.

I.e. you've got the old value in memory, even though the underlying database values have changed.

Try this:

```
@shop.save

# reload the country instance from the database
# to get the updated counter cache value
@country.reload

@new_total_shops = @country.total_shops
```